# How do i only print numbers that contain the number 7?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming. How would i print only the numbers that contain 7 (7,77,777)?

My code is this:

```
for number in range(1000):
    if 7 in number:
        print(number)
```

The error im recieving is "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Comment: `print(*('7' * i for i in range(4)))` seems more efficient…

Comment: You have to be precise about what you mean by "contains 7". Hint: numbers don't have digits; *string* representations in a particular base do.

Comment: Even if this was working, that would be very inefficient. You don't need to check all the numbers if you are just going to print numbers which contains just `7`s.

Comment: "only the numbers that contain 7" or "the numbers that only contain 7"?

Comment: To illustrate the point from @chepner : A normal interpretation of "only the numbers that contain 7" would include (for example) 17, 73 and 5378

Answer (score 2):

Convert the numer into a string, then check if there's an `7` inside the `str(number)`

```py
for number in range(1000):
    if '7' in str(number):
        print(number)
```

```
7
17
27
37
47
57
67
70
71
...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCGvNDcptUghM0@hKDEvPVXD0MDAQNOKSwEIMtMU1M3VQVLFJUUaEIVQKRAoKMrMK4EJ//8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator only works on "sequences", meaning data types that have more than one element such as strings, lists, dictionaries, or tuples.

You are using an integer, which is a single number, regardless of how many digits it has in decimal representation.

You can still us `in` if you first convert the number to a string, like so

```
for number in range(1000):
    s = str(number)
    if '7' in s:
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in range(1000):
  if '7' in str(number):
    print(number)
```

Type casting to a string will allow you to check the presence of a specific character in the number/string. This isnt the ideal solution, but it is a quick and simple way to solve your issue. Since you seem to be new to StackOverflow/programming.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in Python numbers are not iterable. You can't iterate them directly. Either create a string or a list of characters and then search for character '7':

```
for number in range(1000):
    strNum = str(number)
    if '7' in strNum:
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generator function that yields the current number if it includes the desired number. Make sure you cast the integer value to a string using `str()`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def contains_number(n, max = 10):
    for number in range(max):
        if str(n) in str(number):
            yield number

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list(contains_number(7, 1000)))
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution that doesn't involve converting numbers to strings (except for printing):

```
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(10):
        for c in range (10):
            for d in range(10) if 7 in (a,b,c) else [7]:
                print("%d%d%d%d" % (a,b,c,d))
```

The idea is to loop over all possibilities for the first 3 digits; if none of those are a 7, use 7 as the last digit, otherwise you can use any digit (including 7).